# How to use MySQL WHERE IN statement with subquery?

Tags: mysql

The table

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM swaps_products;

+----+---------+-----------+------------+-----------+---------------------+
| id | swap_id | holder_id | swap_to_id | product_id| added               |
+----+---------+-----------+------------+-----------+---------------------+
|  1 |       9 |         3 |          0 |        32 | 2017-01-06 10:43:52 |
|  2 |      11 |        13 |          0 |         3 | 2017-01-06 11:03:45 |
|  3 |      11 |        13 |          0 |         4 | 2017-01-06 11:03:45 |
|  4 |      11 |         3 |          0 |        32 | 2017-01-06 11:03:45 |
|  5 |      11 |         3 |          0 |        31 | 2017-01-06 11:03:45 |
|  6 |      11 |         3 |          0 |        30 | 2017-01-06 11:03:45 |
|  7 |      12 |         3 |          0 |        32 | 2017-01-06 14:16:13 |
|  8 |      12 |         3 |          0 |        31 | 2017-01-06 14:16:13 |
|  9 |      12 |         2 |          0 |         2 | 2017-01-06 14:16:13 |
| 10 |      12 |         2 |          0 |         1 | 2017-01-06 14:16:13 |
| 11 |      13 |        13 |          3 |         3 | 2017-01-12 14:31:44 |
| 12 |      13 |        13 |          3 |         4 | 2017-01-12 14:31:44 |
| 13 |      13 |         3 |         13 |        32 | 2017-01-12 14:31:44 |
| 14 |      13 |         3 |         13 |        31 | 2017-01-12 14:31:44 |
```

To `swap_id = 13` there are four products involved - 3,4,31,32. I need query that would give me all other swaps (list of swap_id) where there are any of 3,4,31,32 products involded.

I have this

```
SELECT sp.swap_id as swap_id, sp.holder_id as holder_id
    -> FROM swaps_products as sp
    -> JOIN swaps as s
    -> ON s.id=sp.swap_id
    -> WHERE (sp.swap_id != 13) AND
    -> (s.rejected IS NULL) AND
    -> ((s.swapped IS NULL) OR (s.swapped2 IS NULL)) AND
    -> (sp.product_id IN (3,4,31,32));
```

The JOIN is not important to problem. This query works but problem is that I know only swap_id. So I tried this:

```
(sp.product_id IN (SELECT product_id FROM swaps_products WHERE swap_id = 13));
```

but got error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'JOIN swaps as s
ON s.id=sp.swap_id
WHERE (sp.swap_id != 13) AND
(s.rejected IS N' at line 2
```

I think problem is that subquery does not return array which is expected from IN statement.

Comment: updated the question with error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IN statements require the result to be a single-column vector of values to check against.

To answer your query directly:

`select * from swaps_products where product_id in
(SELECT product_id FROM swaps_products where swap_id = 13)
and swap_id != 13`

Additionally, based on the error message above, the syntax error you've encountered is pointing at line 2; I suspect you've left out the `FROM swaps_products as sp` part in your `where...in` query.

Comment: I had left out the FROM part.

Comment: happens to the best of us :) happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT y.* 
           FROM swaps_products x 
           JOIN swaps_products y 
             ON y.product_id = x.product_id 
            AND y.swap_id <> 13 
          WHERE x.swap_id = 13;
```